# High frequency detection for missing pulse issues for a high freq. pulse train

Tags: pulse

I know opinion based questions are not welcome but for a project I need to monitor 2MHz pulse train with 1ns ON times. Basically I need to monitor rising edges and if let's say the pulses are not 2MHz several times I want to shut down another system.

My problem is where to start for such a scenario. Would a uC suffice for such high speed application? or are there ad-hoc subsystems for such purposes. I dont want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Missing pulse designs are very much unique.  Write spec on the tolerance and reaction times as well as the rise time, impedance and PW50 duration and allowed loading impedance to avoid reflections.  This can be done with time interval counters and counters. 1ns or 500MHz pulses need careful detection

Comment: 1 ns pulses are too short for the specs of most microcontrollers. The uC might be able to detect them, but I wouldn't rely on that. I would add external circuitry to stretch the 1nS pulse to (maybe) 250nS, which would be 50% duty cycle for a 2MHz train.

Comment: It’s not hard to design, with/out uC but you must ! be precise in your spec tolerances